# PHP locale with money_format not working with fr_CA

Tags: php

I have this simple code:

```
<?php
    setlocale('LC_MONETARY', 'fr_CA.UTF-8');
    echo money_format('%+#10n', '-4562.75834');
    print_r(localeconv());
?>
```

Who normally should give `-4 562,76 $`. But the result is always this:

```
(4 562,76 $)
```

The output of localeconv():

```
Array
(
[decimal_point] => .
[thousands_sep] => 
[int_curr_symbol] => CAD 
[currency_symbol] => $
[mon_decimal_point] => ,
[mon_thousands_sep] =>  
[positive_sign] => 
[negative_sign] => -
[int_frac_digits] => 2
[frac_digits] => 2
[p_cs_precedes] => 0
[p_sep_by_space] => 1
[n_cs_precedes] => 0
[n_sep_by_space] => 1
[p_sign_posn] => 1
[n_sign_posn] => 0
[grouping] => Array
    (
    )

[mon_grouping] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 3
    )
)
```

We can see that negative sign should be `-` but not `()`

The locale on the server (which is Debian 7), is installed:

```
# locale-gen 
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
en_CA.UTF-8... done
fr_CA.ISO-8859-1... done
fr_CA.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

I have tried with PHP 5.4.45 and 5.6.17

Comment: What does `setlocale()` return? Does anything change if you provide a proper `LC_MONETARY` constant rather than a `'LC_MONETARY'` string?

Answer (score 2):

You have put the `LC_MONETARY` between single quotes.

It needs to live as a const variable which is set as not in quotes.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'fr_CA.UTF-8');
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Are you sure? In the php manual it shows the first argument being int and constants are used in the examples. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php. In fact the OP's code is probably casting the string to an int and that is why it isn't working.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, of course, I had my mind in a different context. I'll remove my comment to avoid spreading confusion.